# Implementing an OpenFileDialog with sound file preview

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

I would like to implement an open file dialog or file browser that additionally offers a "Preview" button to play the currently selected sound file (wave format in particular, other formats are not necessary for this application).

- I could create my own form with various controls such as a treeview and listbox to show the folders and files, but I think I would be reinventing the wheel, or if nothing else going to a lot of work for something very simple. Do you recommend doing this?
- Can I modify (inherit) the existing OpenFileDialog and add the sound-playing button to it somehow?
- Is there some free library of custom file pickers that could be utilized? (Provided that the license allows inclusion in a commercial sense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding point 2, I had thought the OpenFileDialog (or SaveFileDialog) weren't extendable in any way - they are provided by the OS.

But, it turns out they could be:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WPFCustomFileDialog.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx

The first one looks like what you're wanting to achieve.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually the second, since this is Winforms rather than WPF. Looks very promising, though! Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Comment: You can use WPF in a WinForms app if you've already got the Framework 3+ dependency... Then maybe you can sex it up a little too... :)

Comment: I have these plans to learn WPF eventually... Unfortunately for this app I don't have the time to upgrade my *noobishness!* :)

Answer (score 2):

Before you get carried away hacking the dialog, consider a simple solution first that leverages the FileOk event.  Create a form named, say, frmPreview.  Give it a constructor that takes a string.  You'll need a Cancel and an OK button and code to play the file.

Display that form like this:

```
        var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        // Set other dlg properties...
        dlg.FileOk += (s, cancel) => {
            using (var prev = new frmPreview(dlg.FileName)) {
                if (prev.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) cancel.Cancel = true;
            }
        };
        if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
            // use the file
            //...
        }
```

Now, whenever the user clicks Open, your preview form shows up.  The user can click Cancel and pick another file from the dialog.

Comment: This is a very viable solution also, I will give it a try in my testing.

Comment: Agreed that hacking the dialog is not optimal, however, as far as UX goes, nor is a popup from a popup...

Answer (score 2):

Found this question whilst searching before asking my own. Possible slight simplification of Hans' answer is to use a standard Message Box rather than having to write your own form. Still a popup on a popup though.

```
    private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog {
            DefaultExt = ".csv",
            Filter = "Wav Files Only (*.wav)|*.wav",
            InitialDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\Media\\",
            CheckFileExists = true
        };
        dlg.FileName = "preselect the existing file if you wish";
        dlg.FileOk += (s, cancel) => {
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.Open(new Uri(dlg.FileName));
            player.Play();
            var msgres = MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName)+"\nUse this sound?", "Sound Playing", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            if (msgres != MessageBoxResult.Yes) cancel.Cancel = true;
            player.Stop(); //in case it is a long sound
        };
        var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result != true) return;
        //do whatever with dlg.FileName ...
    }
```

Using a MessageBox provides a clean standard interface